# Convert python code for Serial Port to MATLAB

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, serial-port

I just want to convert this python code to MATLAB. This is for serial porting. But I cant understand how to change this part of the code to MATLAB. Please help me out.

```
#Check Connected Ports
print("Checking Connected Ports") 
Port=[]
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports(include_links=False)
for i in ports :
    print('Port Found: '+ i.device)
    Port.append(i.device)
print('Port List:'+ str(Port))
```

Comment: Fix the indentation.

Comment: `Port` is not defined.  presumably `port`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below MATLAB command shows all of connected serial ports (in use serial ports):

```
ports = serialportlist
```

Below MATLAB command shows all of serial ports (in use or free serial ports):

```
ports = serialportlist("all")
```

Below MATLAB command shows available serial ports (not in use serial ports):

```
ports = serialportlist("available")
```

In all of above commands, return is a string array with the name of connected ports (or an empty string array if no port is in use), like below:

```
ports = 

1×4 string array

"COM1"    "COM3"    "COM11"    "COM12"
```

If you haven't any device (like Arduino Board) connected to your laptop, you can make virtual serial port using "Virtual Serial Port Driver Software".